# Cannot get Wireguard client configuration to work with tplink 605 vpn l2tp server

Tags: wireguard, l2tp

At home I have a tplink 605 router/vpn server.  I have set up a preshared key l2tp server for incoming traffic.  I've had this working with my iphone using its vpn capability.

I'm now trying to set up a raspberry pi with wireguard to act as a client.  Although every time I start it I get an error.

I've tried to find any docs for this situation, but cannot find any.  Most, if not all situations describe using encryption keys.

My `wg0.conf` file looks like this

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.140.0/24 
DNS = 192.168.17.200

[Peer]

PresharedKey = <client psk>
AllowedIPs = 192.168.17.0/24
Endpoint = home.example.com:192.168.17.1
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Where my home network sits in 192.168.17.0/24 and the tplink router is at 192.168.17.1
and the dns/dhcp server is at 192.168.17.200
it has a "vpn pool" of ip addresses at 192.168.140.0/24

When it starts up is tells me the value of `<client psk>` is too long (it is 10 characters), but what also worries me is that I haven't entered the  anywhere and I haven't found any instruction that says where

There are some "unofficial" references for wg0.conf but the one I look at had no reference to Pre Shared Keys at all.

What should this file look like

Comment: you have no PrivateKey in the `[interface]` and no PublicKey in the `[Peer]` ... and a PresharedKey is a 44 characters long base64 string, just like the Private/Public keys

Comment: `home.example.com:192.168.17.1` isn't valid either, it should be `host:port`, where `host` is either a domain or an IP address, and `port` is a number corresponding to the port the endpoint is listening on (wireguard generally uses 51820, but that's not set in stone)

Comment: @Bravo wireguard isn't listening, my tplink router is the listener here.  Its not very clear what port its using the best docs I can see say a combination of 500, 1723 and 4500, but that is the omada software which I am not using and only in relation to upstream nat portforwarding.  I'll try each of these and see if any work

Comment: @Bravo I did try all those values rather than the IP address after `home.example.com:500` but the error was the same, namely that PresharedKey value is too long

Comment: I would say wherever you're setting that up, it's broken

Comment: @Bravo so would I.  I've given up and use ssh reverse tunnels, set up by a systemd service on boot.  works a treat for my needs (just a couple of ports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a WireGuard client to connect to an L2TP server. You need to use an L2TP client, such as [xl2tpd](https://github.com/xelerance/xl2tpd).

Typically when you use L2TP, you also use IPsec to encrypt its traffic. IPsec may use a preshared symmetric encryption key -- that's likely the preshared key you have. In that case, you need to pair the L2TP client with an IPsec client, such as [Libreswan](https://libreswan.org/), [Openswan](https://openswan.org/), or [strongSwan](https://strongswan.org/).

Here are a few examples of setting up a Linux client for L2TP/IPsec:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Openswan_L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup
- https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#linux
- https://libreswan.org/wiki/VPN_server_for_remote_clients_using_IKEv1_with_L2TP#L2TP/IPsec_client_configuration

Comment: Thanks for those pointers.  I had a brief look at the first one and it looks exactly like I need.  For now I've gone with reverse SSH tunnels as I got fed up not getting it to work, and these reverse tunnels work and also allow me to make out going connections to the client that is also behind a firewall with no holes.